# To trigger a Databricks job in one region by an airflow job running in another region

Tags: airflow, databricks, mwaa, databricks-workflows

We plan to have one common AWS MWAA cluster in us west region which triggers Databricks jobs in different regions.

Is there a way to trigger a Databricks job in one region by an airflow job running in another region? I checked the databricks connection document as [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/connections/databricks.html) but it does not list any region parameters. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow operator doesn't know anything about regions - it just needs URL of the workspace, and personal access token.  That workspace could be in the same region, or in another - it doesn't matter to a Databricks operator.